# How to connect Stripe onboarding with my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into my app. Once a user is created in my apps onboarding, they need to create an account with stripe to get payments. It keeps getting  an error at

```
try {
            accountLink = AccountLink.create(linkParams);
        } catch (StripeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("LINK_PARAMS ERROR:     ", e.toString());
        }
```

The `try{catch}` is not catching the error so I am not seeing what exactly is going on. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I just need to access the onboarding for Stripe, then redirect back to my app. I have read so many articles, I may have my wires crossed.

**Android Manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.stripeTools.ConnectWithStripeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connect_with_stripe"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Godsvong.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER"/>
                <data
                    android:scheme="app"
                    android:host="godsvognapp.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Activity Class:**

```
public class ConnectWithStripeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String RETURN_URL = "app://godsvognapp.com";
    private OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    private ActivityConnectWithStripeBinding binding;
    private Account account = new Account();
    private AccountLink accountLink = new AccountLink();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Stripe.apiKey = MainActivity.STRIPE_KEY;

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setLine1(MainActivity.mUser.getmAddress());
        address.setCity(MainActivity.mUser.getmCity());
        address.setState(MainActivity.mUser.getmState());
        address.setPostalCode(MainActivity.mUser.getmZipCode());

        Person individual = new Person();
        individual.setAddress(address);
        individual.setFirstName(MainActivity.mUser.getmFirstName());
        individual.setLastName(MainActivity.mUser.getmLastName());
        individual.setPhone(MainActivity.mUser.getmPhoneNumber());
        individual.setEmail(MainActivity.mUser.getmEmailAddress());

        account.setIndividual(individual);

        AccountLinkCreateParams linkParams = AccountLinkCreateParams
                .builder()
                .setRefreshUrl(RETURN_URL)
                .setReturnUrl(RETURN_URL)
                .setType(AccountLinkCreateParams.Type.ACCOUNT_ONBOARDING)
                .setCollect(AccountLinkCreateParams.Collect.EVENTUALLY_DUE)
                .build();

        try {
            accountLink = AccountLink.create(linkParams);
        } catch (StripeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("LINK_PARAMS ERROR:     ", e.toString());
        }

        AccountCreateParams params = AccountCreateParams
                .builder()
                .setType(AccountCreateParams.Type.EXPRESS)
                .build();

        try {
            account = Account.create(params);
        } catch (StripeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ACCOUNT ERROR:         ", e.toString());
        }

        binding = ActivityConnectWithStripeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Button connectWithStripe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_with_stripe);

        connectWithStripe.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(accountLink.getUrl())
                    .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), ""))
                    .build();
            httpClient.newCall(request)
                    .enqueue(new Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(@NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                            final Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
                            if (activity == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                                navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home);
                            }

                            if (!response.isSuccessful() || response.body() == null) {
                                // Request failed
                            } else {
                                String body = response.body().string();
                                try {
                                    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(body);
                                    String url = responseJson.getString(accountLink.getUrl());
                                    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                                    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
                                    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(view.getContext(), Uri.parse(url));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
        });
    }

}
```

**Here is the Logcat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hsquaredtechnologies.godsvong, PID: 12735
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hsquaredtechnologies.godsvong/com.hsquaredtechnologies.godsvong.ui.stripeTools.ConnectWithStripeActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4037)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2440)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8641)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1668)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpURLConnectionClient.createStripeConnection(HttpURLConnectionClient.java:124)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpURLConnectionClient.requestStream(HttpURLConnectionClient.java:33)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpURLConnectionClient.request(HttpURLConnectionClient.java:68)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.apply(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient.sendWithTelemetry(HttpClient.java:66)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient.requestWithTelemetry(HttpClient.java:83)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient.lambda$requestWithRetries$0$com-stripe-net-HttpClient(HttpClient.java:145)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient.sendWithRetries(HttpClient.java:109)
        at com.stripe.net.HttpClient.requestWithRetries(HttpClient.java:145)
        at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:58)
        at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:181)
        at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:171)
        at com.stripe.model.AccountLink.create(AccountLink.java:73)
        at com.stripe.model.AccountLink.create(AccountLink.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hsquaredtechnologies.godsvong.ui.stripeTools.ConnectWithStripeActivity.onCreate(ConnectWithStripeActivity.java:90)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8282)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
            ... 12 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12735 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I always err on the side of logging.  I would add some `Log.d()` calls in your `try` block.  Specifically try logging the `accountLink` object returned by the Stripe API and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Thank you!!! I will try that. Does anyone else have any insight into this?